# I am using hero inside flexible space bar in sliverappBar and i am getiing too many heroes error

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

Within each subtree for which heroes are to be animated (i.e. a PageRoute subtree), each Hero must have a unique non-null tag.
In this case, multiple heroes had the following tag: games
Here is the subtree for one of the offending heroes: Hero
tag: games

This is the error that i am getting.

here is my code where i am using it

[image: 1]

Below is the initial screen where i am using hero tag and routing to the next screen
[initial screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TlnH.png)

I checked online that it might happen when heroes are within a list but here i mean its inside a list of slivers but SliperAppBar would only have one instance.

Comment: can you include code-snippet instead of code-image that will reproduce the same error you are facing